# Infinite For Loop issue in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to extract an `ID` from a JSON string that is needed for loading information into a MySQL database. The ID is a 5 or 6 digit number, but the JSON key that contains this number is the URL `net_devices` resource string that has the number at the end like this example:

```
{u'router': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/routers/123456/'}
```

Since there is not a key with just the ID, I have used the following to return just the ID from the JSON key string:

```
url = 'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/net_devices/?fields=router,service_type'

r = json.loads(s.get((url), headers=headers).text)
status = r["data"]


for item in status:
    type = item['service_type']
    router_url = item['router']
    router_id = router_url.replace("https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/routers/", "")
    id = router_id.replace("/", "")
    print id
```

This does indeed return just the ID values I want, and it doesn't matter if the result varies in the number of digits.

**The problem**: This code creates an infinite loop when I include the two lines above the print statement.

How can I change the syntax to allow the loop to run through all the returned `ID`s once, but still strip out everything except the numerical `ID`?

I am new to Python, and just starting to write code again after a very long hiatus since college. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*UPDATE*
Thanks everyone for the feedback! With the help from David and Gerrat, I was able to find the issue that was causing the infinite loop and it was not this segment of the code, but another segment that was not properly indented. I am learning how to properly indent loops in Python, and this was one of my silly mistakes! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: May I ask you to provide a minimal value for "status" that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems pretty unlikely those two lines are creating an infinite loop.  What is the `len()` of a typical status?  What led you to conclude that this was an infinite loop?

Comment: David - a sample of the JSON returned:{
        u'router':  u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/routers/123456/',
        u'service_type': u'EVDO',
    },
    {
        u'router': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/routers/23456/',
        u'service_type': u'Ethernet',
    },
    {
        u'router': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/routers/345678/',
        u'service_type': u'EVDO',
    }
}

Comment: Gerrat - There are about 100 entries in the JSON "status" with a couple of keys each.

Comment: Please edit the updates into the original question.

Comment: I did a quick test on the data you provided, and, after accommodating for the missing: `https://wwww.`, it works fine.  I'm guessing there's something else wrong you're not showing us.

Comment: David and Gerrat - Thanks for looking at my code and providing feedback. I found the issue that was causing the infinite loop and it was not this segment of the code, but another segment that was not properly indented. I am learning how to properly indent loops in Python, and this was one of my silly mistakes! Thanks again for your help!